# Conversion of Strings to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone please help me with a simple code that returns a list as an output to list converted to string? The list is NOT like this:

```
a = u"['a','b','c']"
```

but the variable is like this:

```
a = '[a,b,c]'
```

So,

```
list(a)
```

would yield the following output

```
['[', 'a', ',', 'b', ',', 'c', ']']
```

instead I want the input to be like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I have even tried using the `ast.literal_eval()` function - on using which I got a `ValueError` exception stating the argument is a malformed string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard library that'll load such a list. But you can trivially do this with string processing:

```
a.strip('[]').split(',')
```

would give you your list.

`str.strip()` will remove *any* of the given characters from the start and end; so it'll remove any and all `[` and `]` characters from the start until no such characters are found anymore, then remove the same characters from the end. That suffices nicely for your input sample.

`str.split()` then splits the remainder (minus the `[` and `]` characters at either end) into separate strings at any point there is a comma:

```
>>> a = '[a,b,c]'
>>> a.strip('[]')
'a,b,c'
>>> a.strip('[]').split(',')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us use hack.

```
import string

x = "[a,b,c]"

for char in x:
    if char in string.ascii_lowercase:
        x = x.replace(char, "'%s'" % char)

# Now x is "['a', 'b', 'c']"
lst = eval(x)
```

This checks if a character is in the alphabet(lowercase) if it is, it replaces it with a character with single quotes around it.

**Why not use this solution ?:**

- Fails for duplicate elements
- Fails for elements with more than single characters.
- You need to be careful about confusing single quote and double quotes

**Why use this solution ?:**

- There are no reasons to use this solution rather than Martijn's. But it was fun coding it anyway.

I wish you luck in your problem.